# Image trouble with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my images up to fit within the red lines of the sections i made with css. I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

my HTML:

```
     <!-- Your code goes here --> 
    <div class="container"> 

    <section class="left">  
    <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
    <article>
     <h4>World Capitals</h4>
     <p>A capital city is a city or town, specified by law or constitution,    by     the government of a country, or
    part of a country, such as a state, province, or county. It generally    serves as the location of the government's central meeting 
    place and offices. Most of the country's leaders and officials work in the capital city</p>
    </article>

    <article class="divider">
    <h4>Thailand</h4>
    <figure>
          <figcaption>
              Bangkok
           </figcaption>
           <img src="Bangkok.jpg" alt="Capital of Thailand" title="Bangkok" />
        </figure>   
    <p>
Thailand is a country on Southeast Asia’s Indochina peninsula known for tropical beaches, opulent royal palaces,
 ancient ruins and ornate temples displaying figures of Buddha, a revered symbol. In Bangkok, the capital, an 
 ultramodern cityscape rises next to quiet canal and riverside communities. 
 Commercial hubs such as Chinatown consist of labyrinthine alleys crammed with shophouses, markets and diners.
    </p>
    </article>

    <article class="divider">
    <h4>Egypt</h4>
    <figure>
          <figcaption>
              Cairo
           </figcaption>
           <img src="Cairo.jpg" alt="Capital of Egypt" title="Cairo" />
        </figure>
    <p>
Egypt, a country linking northeast Africa with the Middle East, dates to the time of the pharaohs. 
Millennia-old monuments still sit along the fertile Nile River Valley, including the colossal Pyramids and Sphinx at
 Giza and the hieroglyph-lined Karnak Temple and Valley of the Kings tombs in Luxor. 
    </p>
     <a href="#">Top</a>
     </article>
```

CSS used:

```
section {
   margin-left: 150px;
   border: 3px solid red;  
}

.divider {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}

 img{
      float: right;
      margin: auto;
}
```

I just want the images to appear within their own article sections and not in the middle of the lines I have separating them. Any help would be wonderful! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going for something like this :

```css
section {
    margin-left: 150px;
    border: 3px solid red;  
}

.divider {
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}

.divider:before,
.divider:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.divider:after {
    clear: both;
}

figure, img {
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

h1, h4, p, a, figure {
    margin: 10px;
}

figure {
    max-width: 50%;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <section class="left">  
        <h1>Photo Gallery</h1>
        <article>
            <h4>World Capitals</h4>
            <p>
                A capital city is a city or town, specified by law or constitution,
                by the government of a country, or part of a country, such as a state,
                province, or county. It generally serves as the location of the
                government's central meeting place and offices. Most of the country's
                leaders and officials work in the capital city
            </p>
        </article>
        <article class="divider">
            <h4>Thailand</h4>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Bangkok</figcaption>
                <img src="http://www.seriouseats.com/images/2012/10/20121015-226179-best-dishes-thailand-bangkok.jpg" alt="Capital of Thailand" title="Bangkok" />
            </figure>   
            <p>
                Thailand is a country on Southeast Asia’s Indochina peninsula
                known for tropical beaches, opulent royal palaces, ancient ruins and
                ornate temples displaying figures of Buddha, a revered symbol. In
                Bangkok, the capital, an ultramodern cityscape rises next to quiet
                canal and riverside communities. Commercial hubs such as Chinatown
                consist of labyrinthine alleys crammed with shophouses, markets and 
                diners.
            </p>
        </article>
        <article class="divider">
            <h4>Egypt</h4>
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Cairo</figcaption>
                <img src="http://cdn.ek.aero/english/images/Cairo_tcm233-2363745.jpg" alt="Capital of Egypt" title="Cairo" />
            </figure>
            <p>
                Egypt, a country linking northeast Africa with the Middle East, dates
                to the time of the pharaohs. Millennia-old monuments still sit along
                the fertile Nile River Valley, including the colossal Pyramids and
                Sphinx at Giza and the hieroglyph-lined Karnak Temple and Valley of
                the Kings tombs in Luxor. 
            </p>
            <a href="#">Top</a>
        </article>
    </section>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4rzzh713/1/))